# Locate and click element that contains specific text

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, appium

This question has probably been asked before, but I can't seem to track down its location...But, I am trying to find a way to select an element on screen that has the same 'resource-id' as another element, but not by locating both elements and then selecting the 2nd one, for instance, since they are both not always on the screen. Also, I can't just use XPATH with Class + Text, since the Text of the element can/will change. I was wondering if there is a way to use resource-id plus a particular string within the 'text' of the element (a string that I know will not change). Or possibly use XPATH with Class + 'text' contains some sub-text, e.g,

```
    get_code = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[@text.contains='differentiatable sub-string']")))
    element.click()
```

Image attached shows one of the elements that I need to be able to differentiate between. The other element, not pictured, has the same attributes with the exception of 'Text' and 'Package.'

[image]

I have tried

```
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "android:id/big_text"), "validation"))
    element.click()
```

Where 'validation' is a sub-string that allows me to differentiate (it is contained in the second element, and that string is always present), but this fails because you can't 'click' a value of True or False  : )

Comment: I thought             element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "android:id/big_text"), 'validation'))
            element.click()   might work, but I have the same issue...'AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'click'

Answer (score 0):

You could use this, if you're just looking to match an element containing a string

(Note  I like to use <kbd>.</kbd> rather than <kbd>`text()`</kbd> to make the xpaths a bit shorter.)

Also I don't know the python API so I'm taking for granted your commands were correct (other than the xpath).  I am familiar with the Java.  I hope this helps (I did remove what looked like an extra set of parenthesis though).

[Here's an example of locating Xpath for Android from saucelabs](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started+with+Appium+for+Mobile+Native+Application+Testing#GettingStartedwithAppiumforMobileNativeApplicationTesting-TheExampleApplication)

(Note with **contains use** a <kbd>,</kbd>)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
get_code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//TextView[contains(.,'differentiatable sub-string')"])))
element.click()
```

You could use this to match the string exactly 
(Note when you want an **exact match use** a <kbd>=</kbd> ):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
get_code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//TextView[.='differentiatable sub-string')"])))
element.click()
```

And this to match the text exactly but trim surrounding whitespace, use **normalize-space(text())** or **normalize-space(.)**:
You could use this to match the string exactly:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
get_code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//TextView[normalize-space(.)='differentiatable sub-string'])))
element.click()
```

It looks like the previous Xpaths weren't working.  You can try either of these:
I didn't realize with Android text is an actual property of an element.  So you may have to use the following rather than what I was doing before:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
get_code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//android.widget.Textview
[@class='android.widget.Textview' and contains(@text,'Charging')"])))
element.click()
```

Or 
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
    get_code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//android.widget.Textview
    [@class='android.widget.Textview' and contains(.,'Charging')"])))
    element.click()

If neither of those work

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
get_code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,//FrameLayout[1]//LinearLayout[2]//TextView[1])))
element.click()
```

Or you may need to use the full class name (Please correct the element names if these are not correct):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
get_code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.LinearLayout[2]//android.widget.TextView[1])))
element.click()
```

Comment: element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(),'validation')]"))
            element.click()    --   is giving me "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"

Comment: I think I missed some parenthesis in my examples, so I looked at the Selenium for Python documentation and updated my code examples.

Comment: Same result when using the modified version, 'get_code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(),'validation')]"))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)'

Comment: Any other ideas? Or maybe a modification to the formatting of your first answer that makes it only 2 arguments...

Comment: I put in a few more suggestions, if any of these works please leave a comment, so I can update the others for future people looking for help on Xpath for Android.